# First Person/Fly mode camera is moving by itself

Tags: edit-mode

I tried searching but didn't find this problem.

I've been having problems with the Shift+F mode as of a few hours ago. Never had the problem before and I haven't installed anything new, so I'm convinced it's a key I pressed that might have messed something up.

When I enter first person/fly mode, sometimes, it doesn't respond to my mouse inputs and I have to right click out of it. Most other times, whenever I move the mouse to look around, the camera will continue to move to the right after I have stopped moving my mouse. I know there isn't any mouse input going on because when I exit out of fly mode, the mouse cursor stays perfectly still.

I exited out of all of my softwares that deal with mouse inputs (logitech software and stuff), I restarted blender, etc.

The weird part is, when I open a new file, I still have the problem, but it's harder to duplicate the issue. 
Also, there's nothing showing up at the little console thingy at the top.

I have no idea what I might have done to cause this.